# How do I use the DirectX libraries and functions in C++ modules (conveniently)?

Tags: c++, directx, c++20, linker-errors, c++-modules

I'm trying to use C++ modules for a DirectX 12 graphics engine. I attempt to use a simple API call like `CreateDXGIFactory2` and the function just fails; it returns a `E_NOINTERFACE` return code.

Here's a bare bones example of a program.

**`Factory.ixx`**

```
module;
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <cassert>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")

export module Factory;

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

export class Factory
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory7> pFactory {};

    public:

    Factory() noexcept
    {
        HRESULT HResult { S_OK };
        HResult = CreateDXGIFactory2( DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pFactory ) );
        assert( HResult == S_OK );
    }
};
```

**`Main.cpp`**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
import Factory;

uint32_t main( void )
{
    Factory factory {};
    return 0;
}
```

This will build, but the assert fails. In debug, the value of HResult happens to be `E_NOINTERFACE`. In my testing, it seems that the module file isn't loading the symbols from the library. I've tried quite a few things, some of which I feel I have forgotten at this point, so here's a not-so-exhaustive list in no particular order:

- **Use a module definition file.**

You can use a .def file to export symbols/attributes(?) of a library. Here's the text of the .def file I made to test this:

```
EXPORTS
    CreateDXGIFactory2=dxgi.lib
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. The linker returns an error of `LNK1120: unresolved external symbol dll`. I attempted to use an absolute path as well, but the "10.0.___" part of the Windows SDK path confused the linker during parse... moving on.

- **Use a dummy call from a source file to force load the symbols.**

This method *does* work. If I alter `Main.cpp` in this way,

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <wrl.h>
import Factory;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
uint32_t main( void )
{
    HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory2( DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG, IID_PPV_ARGS( &ComPtr<IDXGIFactory7>() ) );
    Factory factory {};
    return 0;
}
```

the symbol will load and be usable in the `Factory.ixx` file when it comes to runtime; that is, the `CreateDXGIFactory2` function will return an `S_OK` in the `Factory` constructor and the `pFactory` pointer will have an address. However, I'm hoping there is a better method to use than this, since placing all of the functions I will use from the `dxgi.lib` and other libraries into a source file sounds tedious and slow.

- **Use the force load linker option.**

The point is to include the following command line to the linker: `/WHOLEARCHIVE:dxgi.lib`. While this *does* build, even without the `#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")` in the global module section, the function `CreateDXGIFactory2` still returns a nasty `E_NOINTERFACE` result. Another issue with this solution is, when forcing multiple libraries to load in this way, you get duplicated symbols. This has its own solution, of defining a default library to prefer symbols from; e.g. `/DEFAULTLIB:d3d12.lib`, but this doesn't fix the multiple symbols issue and definitely still doesn't fix the `CreateDXGIFactory2` function.

- **Use `import` rather than `#include`.**

Apparently, imports only work on modules, not libraries. I don't know why ChatGPT continues telling me to do this.

- **Add `dxgi.lib` to your additional dependencies.**

The libraries included in the Windows SDK are already linked by default. Consequently, explicitly adding the library as a dependency doesn't resolve the error.

- **Use a higher interface of `IDXGIFactory`.**

If the `CreateDXGIFactory2` function can correctly call in a source file with the `IDXGIFactory7` version of the interface, then the module should be able to as well. Regardless, this does not work.

- **Turn back time completely and use an older version of the `dxgi` header.**

```
module;
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <cassert>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")

export module Factory;

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

export class Factory
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory> pFactory {};

    public:

    Factory() noexcept
    {
        HRESULT HResult { S_OK };
        HResult = CreateDXGIFactory( IID_PPV_ARGS( &pFactory ) );
        assert( HResult == S_OK );
    }
};
```

This does not work.

**Some (possibly incorrect) additional information**

As it goes, there is a feature of the module system called "import on first use".

Let me know what you think! Any and all suggestions appreciated!

Comment: E_NOINTERFACE just means this interface is not available. This https://pastebin.com/raw/LBCHybG6 works fine on Windows 10, version 1809 as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_6/nn-dxgi1_6-idxgifactory7. Just make sure you're running off this minimum Windows version, or ask for another IDXGIFactory (maybe you don't need version 7).

Comment: @SimonMourier I understand the meaning of the error code. To clarify, I'm trying to get this working with C++ modules. The pastebin you've linked is essentially the code I have written above, which I have tested and works with headers/source files, but does not work with the module system in my project. Maybe you were trying to make a different point in your comment; in that case, it is completely lost on me and I may need clarification, please.

Comment: Ok sorry, it wasn't clear the same program was working w/o modules. What happens is `__uuidof(IDXGIFactory7)` (called by `IID_PPV_ARGS`) returns the null guid. You can fix it with something like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/bdFwFJhx . What you can see when looking at disassembly here https://i.imgur.com/W5MZjFS.png is the `_GUID_a4966eed_76db_44da_84c1_ee9a7afb20a8` internal symbol contains only 0 when starting like in your code, like a lazy initialization issue specific to module. Looks like a bug to me. You should report to Microsoft.

Comment: @SimonMourier Well, that's an exceptionally disappointing outcome. Even using the `IID` provided by the `initguid.h` header for `IDXGIFactory7` does not fix the problem either.

Comment: Are you sure? this works fine for me while I could reproduce before.

Comment: @SimonMourier It seems I should have tested a little more before posting, as I got it working shortly after. It’s certainly a bit more tedious than I would have liked, but I’m glad to have this working after months of searching for a solution. Thanks.